# Translate texture from outer bounds to center

Tags: texturing

The motion I want is very close to water soaking in the sinkhole (just without spiral aspect).

**I'd like to use Noise texture on a flat plane** - it should move to the center and preserve pattern as much as possible, without morphing into "Saturn rings"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could manipulate texture space coordinates. You would need to make one go from the center outwards and then animate a value added to it. Gradient texture could be used:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, I was thinking about that. But it produces too much dissolving effect, rather than actual moving to center

Comment: This is cool. I will experiment with your node tree.